# Create multiple folders with text file inside in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to create 1000 folders each with a single text file inside
eg
C:...\Customer1\Customer1.txt
C:...\Customer2\Customer2.txt
C:...\Customer3\Customer3.txt
.
.
.
etc to 1000

I can create a single folder and file with command prompt:

cd C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\1000 folders
md Customer1
echo.>Customer1\Customer1.txt

I'm just not sure how to duplicate this without manually typing out 1000 folder names... how would I do this? with a batch file?

Comment: A loop would do this for you - read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

If the file `C:\Temp\Create.cmd` contains this;

```
for /L %%G in (1,1,2) DO
(
    mkdir "Customer%%G"
    echo: > Customer%%G\Customer%%G.txt
)
```

Running it in C:\Temp will create these directories and files;

```
C:\Temp\Customer1
C:\Temp\Customer1\Customer1.txt
C:\Temp\Customer2
C:\Temp\Customer2\Customer2.txt
```

To create more of them, change the line `for /L %%G in (1,1,X)` where **x** is the number you actually want (1000 I think you said). I'd prefer starting out small though incase something is messed up.

Comment: This is the very first time I've tried writing in cmd prompt or attempting a batch file so please forgive my ignorance...
I tried creating a .cmd file in the directory with the following:

@ECHO OFF

for /L %%G in (1,1,2) DO
(
    mkdir "Customer%%G"
    echo: > Customer%%G\Customer%%G.txt
)

but it didn't work. I've looked at batch file examples online and they seem to have a lot more code in, is there more I need to include in the batch file?

Comment: Noticed a bit of a difference when I ran cmd as admin eventhough I have the rights to the directories. Try running rightclicking your .cmd-file and run it as admin if possible and see if that works for ya.